# How to ffmpeg encode using same codecs and parameters as certain file has?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding, xvid

I need to merge two different video files and I am using [LosslessCut](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/) for the task. Yet it says that the files need to have the same codecs, dimension, framerate.

Source is mkv V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC with Vorbis, destination is avi xvid with ac3.

- Full parameters of both files using ffmpeg encoding

```
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 6.20 MiB
Duration                                 : 46 s 280 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 1 124 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.45.100

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Advanced Simple@L5
Format settings                          : BVOP2
Format settings, BVOP                    : 2
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (MPEG)
Muxing mode                              : Packed bitstream
Codec ID                                 : XVID
Codec ID/Hint                            : XviD
Duration                                 : 46 s 280 ms
Bit rate                                 : 921 kb/s
Width                                    : 576 pixels
Height                                   : 432 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 3:2
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.148
Stream size                              : 5.08 MiB (82%)
Writing library                          : XviD 64

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Commercial name                          : Dolby Digital
Codec ID                                 : 2000
Duration                                 : 46 s 254 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 192 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 28.711 FPS (1536 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 1.06 MiB (17%)
Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 35  ms (0.87 video frame)
Interleave, preload duration             : 347  ms
Service kind                             : Complete Main
```

- Parameters of the file that I want to recode/encode (in order to have parameters shown above):

```
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 2.36 MiB
Duration                                 : 27 s 999 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 706 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.45.100
Writing library                          : Lavf58.45.100
ErrorDetectionType                       : Per level 1

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 27 s 933 ms
Bit rate                                 : 564 kb/s
Width                                    : 854 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.303 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.045
Stream size                              : 1.88 MiB (80%)
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : Vorbis
Format settings, Floor                   : 1
Codec ID                                 : A_VORBIS
Duration                                 : 27 s 837 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -52 ms
Stream size                              : 435 KiB (18%)
Writing application                      : Lavc58.91.100
Writing library                          : libVorbis (Reducing Environment) (20200704 (Reducing Environment))
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

How can I please extract all the data from the destination file and input it as a parameter to a FFmpeg source file encode command? I was looking up if there is a script for this, but can not find.

Comment: There are 3 files involved here: the two different video files you need to "merge", and the output that you want to be a certain format, but you only showed info about 2 files.

Comment: @llogan thx, for the feedback, when i was talking about source and destination i meant that i want source file to have parameters of the destination file... or at least all possible parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libxvid -vf scale=-2:432 -r 25 -profile:v 0 -level 5 -vtag XVID -mpeg_quant 1 -b:v 921k -bf 2 -c:a ac3 -ac 2 -ar 44100 output.avi
```

Comment: That is very disappointing. For such a program weren't difficult to read the source parameters and use the same. Now I should organize multiple context menu items instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any good solution yet, but **[there is an Linux bash script](https://github.com/slrslr/Miscellaneous-bash-scripts/blob/master/mediainfocomparefiles)** attempt to automate the task of finding differences in video fragments to be merged and suggest commands to fix the differences.

Answer (score 0):

This is close: "scale one video to match another without pre-defining the dimensions", put two videos side-by-side and have the 2nd video scale to match the 1st:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:h=in_h:[v1][v0];[v0][v1]hstack[vo]" -map "[vo]" ./output-video.mp4
```

[source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling)